# Overlay issues when the image is changed or resized

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add UI elements over the top of an image by using pure HTML and CSS only. Here's the expected result
[image]
My code is working as expected but there are two issues. Here are the issues:

1. When I changed the image into a Adobe Illustrator one the UI elements are disappeared
   [image]
2. **SOLVED** At certain point the background image will not responsive while the UI elements keep changing it size when the window is upsized
   [image]

Any idea where did I go wrong? This is my attempt

```css
.plane-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

.deck {
  display: flex;
}

.arrow {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.plane-container .overlay .main-deck {
  width: 67%;
  height: 23%;
  margin-top: 19.3%;
  margin-left: 16.5%;
  position: absolute;
}

.plane-container .overlay .lover-deck {
  width: 20.3%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-top: 27.2%;
  margin-left: 16.5%;
  position: absolute;
}

.plane-container .overlay .aft-deck {
  width: 16.7%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-top: 27.2%;
  margin-left: 55%;
  position: absolute;
}

.plane-container div img {
  position: relative;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="plane-container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="main-deck deck">
      <div class="arrow" style="width: 5%;">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
      </div>
      <div style="background:blue; width: 90%; height: 100%;">
        
      </div>
      <div class="arrow" style="width: 5%;">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lover-deck deck">
      <div class="arrow" style="width: 10%;">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
      </div>
      <div style="background:red; width: 80%; height: 100%;">
        
      </div>
      <div class="arrow" style="width: 10%;">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aft-deck deck">
      <div class="arrow" style="width: 10%;">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
      </div>
      <div style="background:purple; width: 80%; height: 100%;">
        
      </div>
      <div class="arrow" style="width: 10%;">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- Image from Adobe Illustrator -->  
    <!-- <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/j5ggYMjt/from-ai.png" /> -->
    
    <!-- Original Image -->  
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/V6ypHG5T/red.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/airlangga/yz36bw9o/15/) link

**EDIT 1**

Problem 2 is solved by Terek Janczik

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your code to fix the boxes not sitting in the correct location when the screen is resized beyond a certain width:

```
.plane-container div img{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see. I've tried your code and it works. Thank you!